# How to show the fields or field key of ACF in email?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I use ACF plugins and ACF for WooCommerce. If the user Woocommerce changes his data, the administrator receives an email about these changes.

Here is the complete code:

```
if( !class_exists('WooCommerceNotifyChanges') ){

class WooCommerceNotifyChanges{

function __construct(){
// customer saves main account data
add_action('woocommerce_save_account_details', array( $this, 'woocommerce_send_notification' ), 15, 1 );

}

function woocommerce_send_notification( $user_id ){
$body       = '';
$to         = 'info@domain.com';    //address that will receive this email
$subject    = 'One of your customers has updated their information.';

$user      = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user_name = $user->user_login;

$body .= '<table>';
$body .= '<tr><td><strong>' . __("Account") . '</strong></td></tr>';
$body .= '<tr><td>Username: </td><td>' . $user_name                                         . '</td></tr>';
$body .= '<tr><td>First name: </td><td>' . $user->billing_first_name . '</td></tr>';
$body .= '<tr><td>Last name: </td><td>' . $user->billing_last_name  . '</td></tr>';
$body .= '<tr><td>Phone: </td><td>' . get_field( 'user_phone', "user_{$user_id}" ) . '</td></tr>';
$body .= '<tr><td>Age: </td><td>' . get_field( 'user_age', "user_{$user_id}" ) . '</td></tr>';
$body .= '</table>';    

//set content type as HTML
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;');

//send email
if( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers ) ){
    //echo 'email sent';
}else{
    //echo 'email NOT sent';                
}
//exit();
}
}
new WooCommerceNotifyChanges(); 
}
```

I created several custom fields and show these fields in the user's account.

In an email to the administrator, these fields "user_phone" and others are not shown.

The "ACF for WooCommerce" plugin, for example, saves the "user_phone" field in the database as meta_key: "field_5b7e4f388fd11" and meta_value: "+79998006655".

[image]

In my code, the field is displayed like this:

```
get_field( 'user_phone', "user_{$user_id}" )
```

When I put the field key "field_5b7e4f388fd11" instead of the field name...

```
get_field( 'field_5b7e4f388fd11', "user_{$user_id}" )
```

I get an email with empty fields.

How can I fix this problem?

---

**Update:** I can directly use get_user_meta:

```
get_user_meta($user_id, 'field_5b7e4f388fd11', $single=true);
```

This option works, but if I replacing the existing field value, for example, “+79998006655” with the new “+78009995566”, then everything is stored correctly in the database, and the old version of “+79998006655” comes to the administrator’s email.

If the custom field is a checkbox, then it is correctly stored in the database, but only “Array” is shown in the administrator email.

Yes, and the email to the administrator comes a long time.

How can this be remedied?

Answer (score 0):

There is no needs to add braces

Try this code:

```
get_field( 'user_age', "user_$user_id" )
```

UPDATE 1:

More information at [ACF Official docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-user/).

Example from the ACF docs:

```
// This example will retrieve a field value from a user with an ID of 1.
$variable = get_field('field_name', 'user_1');
```

UPDATE 2:

Try this:

get_field( 'user_phone', 'user_' . $user_id )

Comment: I mean ''}" and "{". Yes you have it in your code: `user_{$user_id}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why then do developers advise themselves to write, as I have in the code? (((

Comment: Unfortunately, but even your changes did not help. The fields in the email to the administrator are empty.

Comment: Have you checked the $user_id ? Is not it the id of admin?

Comment: Check the UPDATE 2 in answer.

Comment: It still does not work. That's the problem. The "ACF for WooCommerce" plugin saves the "user_phone" field in the database as meta_key: "field_5b7e4f388fd11" and meta_value: "+79998006655". 

If you change "field_5b7e4f388fd11" to "user_phone" in the database, then the fields in the email to the administrator are displayed. Therefore, I thought that in my code it is better to display the field keys.

Comment: I would suggest to try this: get_field( 'field_5b7e4f388fd11', "user_{$user_id}" )

Comment: This option also does not work. I updated my question.